# Stacked barplot of small data set in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have a a file which contains two lists: with names in first column and numbers in secound column.

I would like to make a bar plot with names on x-axis and numbers on y-axis.

I used melt(mydata) and got a file with 3 columns: V1 (names) variable (V2) value (number)

Then I tried

```
ggplot(dat, aes(x = "V1", y= "value", fill = "variable")) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

The I got: [Stacked barplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2bCW.jpg)

Any ideas where I go wrong?

Comment: Don't quote variables inside `aes`..

Comment: It doesn't work if I don't.. Then it says 'value' not found

Comment: Did you just run `melt(mydata)` or `mydata <- melt(mydata)`? You need to reassign the data to something for a permanent change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're over complicating it:

```
ggplot(dat, aes(V1, value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```